# Bouncing ball with friction.

Tags: numerical-methods, physics, simulation

I am trying to write freefem code (same language as c++) for a bouncing ball, but I am not able to notice the result of friction force. At each time the rigid ball hits the rigid ground, the horizontal velocity must be decreased. While I am trying the velocity is not decreased, it is still bouncing for a fixed height.

Any hint please, I will be thankful for any indication that help me proceed in writing the code.

```
for(n=0;n<200;n++){

 ax = 0;
 ay = (Fgy+Fry+Fby+Fhy)/M;  // Forces that acts on the ball in the y direction and M is the mass of the ball  

 V01=V01+dt*ax;
 V02=V02+dt*ay;

 if(G02<4){
  G02=4;
  V02=V02*(0.95);
 }

 if(G02>33.){
  G02=33.;
  V02=V02*(0.95);
 }

 if(G01>46.){
  G01=46.;
  V01=V01*(0.95);
 }

 if(G01<4.){
  G01=4.;
  V01=V01*(0.95);
 }

 G01=G01+dt*V01;
 G02=G02+dt*V02;

 ...plot...

}
```

$(G01,G02)$ is the coordinates of center of mass of the ball and $(V01,V02)$ the velocity vector of the ball ,$ax$ and $ay$ are the 2 components of the acceleration. The domain is $[0,50]\times [0,37]$ and the radius of the ball is $r=4$.

$0.95$ is the value of restitution.

Comment: This sounds like it belongs in https://physics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Friction will turn convert the lateral motion of the ball into rotational motion.  Soon enough the ball has the rotational speed that matches the lateral motion and it will not slow down any more.  But again, this is a physics issue and not math.

Comment: if your model decreases the horizontal speed only, then certainly the vertical speed remains unchanged,  .. and so the bouncing height

Comment: @DougM  what I am doing is considering fluid-structure interaction problem, and to satisfy the theoretical result I am doing numerical simulations. The rigid ball is thrown and I am watching its bounce, I have considered drag,hydrodynamic,gravitational and buoyant forces. But my problem is with slowing down this motion

Comment: @GCab I have also tried to multiply the vertical speed be a number less than one at each iteration,but nothing changes

Comment: @DougM so what I am doing is dealing with simulations and programming .. nut pure physical problem

Comment: then definitely something is wrong with your code.

Comment: @GCab is it a right idea to multiply by restitution?

Comment: Yes, multiplying the vertical velocity by a constant less than $1$ is a reasonable model.  You need to understand why that is not working for you.

Comment: I think your problem is concerning the so called restitution coefficient associated to  elastic phenomena.

Comment: @Cesareo what should I do then?

Comment: First, make sure you have the physics correct. You need to search and post to [Physics.SE]. Then, make sure your code is correct. You need to post to [SO] if you have any specific questions, or [CodeReview.SE].

Comment: Please show us your math, or in concept the efforts you have taken.

Comment: @ja72 I will add a part of the code I have written to the question

Comment: Do you understand the physics of bouncing a rotating ball, at least in 2D?

Comment: @ja72 yes, My code includes Navier stokes equations too, I have determined the velocity of the fluid and its changes due to the fluid-ball interaction and I have determined the angular velocity of the ball and updated its angle of rotation in each iteration.

Comment: @ja72 my problem is in updating the vertical and horizontal velocity at each time the ball hits the ground or the wall , it is still bouncing with the same height

Comment: @Math1995 please clean up your code so that it is properly formatted and so that all terms are defined. I can try to help you fix it but right now I can't even figure out which part is solving for the frictional impulses...

Comment: @user7530 is it clear now?

Comment: You need to _reverse_ the sign of the velocity components after the bounce. Like `V02= -V02*(0.95);`. Also you never modify the rotational speed, which is affected by friction.

Comment: @ja72 this gives the same result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the general planar case of a ball impacting the ground with friction $\mu$. The general motion of the ball is described by the velocity components $\dot{x}$, $\dot{y}$ and $\dot{\theta}$ just before the impact.

[image: BallBounce1]

At the moment of impact, two impulses act on the ball $N$ and $F$ altering the motion of the ball afterward by

$$ \begin{aligned}
  \Delta \dot{x} & = \frac{1}{m} F \\
  \Delta \dot{y} & = \frac{1}{m} N \\
  \Delta \dot{\theta} & = \frac{1}{I} r F
\end{aligned}$$

where $m$ is the mass and $I$ the mass moment of inertia for the ball about the center of mass.

Now consider what must happen after the impact. The vertical velocity should be a fraction of the impacting velocity

$$ \dot{y} + \Delta \dot{y} = -\epsilon\, \dot{y} $$

where $\epsilon$ is the coefficient of restitution. Use 0 for plastic impact, and 1 for purely elastic.

In the horizontal direction, things get more interesting. Consider first the situation of high friction where the surface of the ball acquires the speed of the ground (zero). The surface velocity is $v = \dot{x} + r\,\dot{\theta}$ or

$$ (\dot{x} + r\,\dot{\theta}) + (\Delta\dot{x} + r\,\Delta\dot{\theta}) = 0 $$

Use these two equations to find the impulses

$$ \begin{aligned}
 N & = -(1+\epsilon)\, m\, \dot{y} \\
 F & = - \frac{1}{\frac{1}{m} + \frac{r^2}{I}} (\dot{x} + r\,\dot{\theta})
\end{aligned} $$

Now you check if the frictional impulse is more than traction.

$$ F = \begin{cases} 
-\mu |N| {\rm sign}(\dot{x} + r\,\dot{\theta}) & |F| > \mu |N| \\
\mbox{unmodified} & |F| \le \mu |N| \end{cases} $$

Finally, apply the impluses with

$$ \begin{aligned}
  \Delta \dot{x} & = \frac{1}{m} F \\
  \Delta \dot{y} & = \frac{1}{m} N \\
  \Delta \dot{\theta} & = \frac{1}{I} r F
\end{aligned}$$

and continue the simulation.

Comment: excuse my ignorance, but what does the term "sign" mean in the line: −μ|N|sign(x˙+rθ˙)

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any part of your code that attempts to apply friction (you've implemented a *coefficient of restitution*, which is also a dissipative phenomenon but is in fact rather unrelated to friction.)

A very simple model of frictional impact would be a Coulomb law.

1) You resolved the impact by applying  an impulse (change in momentum) in the direction of the *contact normal* $\hat{n}$. Compute the magnitude of the normal impulse: $J_n = p^+\cdot n - p^- \cdot n,$ where $p^-$ and $p^+$ are the momentum of the ball before and after the impact. Notice that $J_n$ is always positive.

2) Compute the tangential momentum $p^{+}_{t} = p^+ - (p^+\cdot \hat{n})\hat n.$ (You could also use the pre-impact momentum; the value would be the same.)

3) Compute the magnitude of the friction impulse using Coulomb's law: $$J_t = \min(\|p_t^+\|, \mu J_n)$$
where $\mu$ is the coefficient of friction. The first term in the minimum is there to ensure that your frictional impulse at most stops, but never reverses, the tangential momentum of the ball. The second term enforces the friction cone constraint---the harder the ball hits the wall, the more friction is allowed.

4) Apply the friction impulse: add $-J_t \frac{p_t^+}{\|p_t^+\|}$ to the ball's post-impact momentum.

This scheme is extremely simplistic and will not work if you have multiple simultaneous collisions, if the friction impulses themselves cause new collisions, etc. But it is hopefully a start.